# Pulling Print Drivers from a Server and Installing them to a Workstation Using Powershell

Tags: powershell, printing, driver

**Context:** My ultimate goal is to wake up from print Nightmare. To do this, I plan on creating a script that will be deployed via GPO that installs print drivers and network printers. Below is the test script I'm working with.

**Script:**

```
pnputil.exe /a "\\j001-hal2010\HP Universal Print Driver\pcl6-x64-7.0.0.24832\hpcu250u.inf"
Add-PrinterDriver -Name "HP Universal Printing PCL 6" -InfPath "C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\hpcu250u.inf"
Add-PrinterPort -Name "TCPPort:10.1.1.193" -PrinterHostAddress "10.1.1.193"
Add-Printer -DriverName "HP Universal Printing PCL 6" -Name "Cust Service HP Color LaserJet M653" -PortName "TCPPort:10.1.1.193"
```

**Problem:** My issue is that the `pnputil.exe /a "\\j001-hal2010\HP Universal Print Driver\pcl6-x64-7.0.0.24832\hpcu250u.inf"` comes back with the following error:

> Adding the driver package failed : Invalid INF passed as parameter.

When I insert a Wilcard for the INF, I receive the same error:
`pnputil.exe /a "\\j001-hal2010\HP Universal Print Driver\pcl6-x64-7.0.0.24832\*.inf"`

> Adding the driver package failed : Invalid INF passed as parameter.
>
> Total attempted:              0 Number successfully imported: 0

**Resources:**

https://www.pdq.com/blog/using-powershell-to-install-printers/

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/pnputil-command-syntax

Comment: You don't say if it's pnputil or the powershell command that produces the error. I would assume it's pnputil. Have you tried using a wildcard for the inf filename instead?

Comment: @DougMaurer Excellent question....here are the results when I put in a wildcard:
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> pnputil.exe /a "\\j001-hal2010\HP Universal Print Driver\pcl6-x64-7.0.0.24832\*.inf"
Microsoft PnP Utility

Adding the driver package failed : Invalid INF passed as parameter.

Total attempted:              0
Number successfully imported: 0

I also edited the question to reflect that attempt as well. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: Are you invoking this command remotely or locally?

Comment: @DougMaurer
I am running it locally from the workstation

Comment: you can try to export the driver from the printer server using `Export-WindowsDriver` and then specifying the corresponding exported driver.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are not authenticated to the source.  I got this until I added a net use x: \j001-hal2010\ and entered a username and password.  I could then run pnputil.exe /a "\j001-hal2010\HP Universal Print Driver\pcl6-x64-7.0.0.24832*.inf"